# Moving ASP.net website from II6 to II7

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, asp.net

I know I'm probably doing something terribly wrong, but I copied the source files from one computer to another running IIS7, then I visit the site and get this error:

```
Error Summary
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
Detailed Error Information
Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    BeginRequest
Handler Not yet determined
Error Code  0x80070021
Config Error    This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".
Config File \\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\mysite\web.config
Requested URL   http://localhost:80/mysite/mysite/default.aspx
Physical Path   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\mysite\default.aspx
Logon Method    Not yet determined
Logon User  Not yet determined
Config Source
   96:      </modules>
   97:      <handlers>
   98:          <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This quick guide will help you migrate a Web site from IIS 6.0 to IIS 7 by using the Web Deployment Tool.](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/427/migrate-a-web-site-from-iis-60-to-iis-7/)

[IIS6 to IIS7 migration tips / tricks](http://weblogs.asp.net/steveschofield/archive/2008/09/04/iis6-to-iis7-migration-tips-tricks.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Is the Application Pool hosting this Application running in Classic Mode? The article Luke has pointed you too should provide the solution